# Layers reference from Geoprocessing using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, geoprocessing, feature-layer

I am using ArcObjects (ArcGIS 10.1) in .NET with some geoprocessing. It works great. There is an option to add the resulting feature class to the map. That works great too. However how do I get a reference to this layer to move it to a group layer?

```vb
Dim GP As GeoProcessor = New GeoProcessor
GP.AddOutputsToMap = True 'True if we want to add outputs to map, False if we dont.

Dim parameters As IVariantArray = New VarArray
parameters.Add(inDatasets)     
parameters.Add(toPointFullName)
parameters.Add("")             

Dim res As IGeoProcessorResult = GP.Execute("Merge_management", parameters, Nothing)
'todo: how do I get a reference to ILayer of the resulting layer added to map?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following in VBA shows how to create a layer object that you could then add to a group layer in the map.

```vb
Dim res As IGeoProcessorResult
If res.Status = esriJobSucceeded Then
    Dim pGPUtil As IGPUtilities4
    Set pGPUtil = New GPUtilities
    Dim pFL As IFeatureLayer
    Set pFL = pGPUtil.OpenFeatureLayerFromString(toPointFullName)
End If
```

Comment: Ahh didn't know u could do that. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: Works great except I changed it to OpenFeatureClassFromString which gave me a feature class then i could turn that into a layer object. Thanks!